# Extract json data from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Here is my js function

```
<script>        
function get_class_group(class_id) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/get_class_group/' + class_id ,
            success: function(response)
            {
                var obj = response;
                alert(obj);
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

This gives me output like

```
[{"section_id":"13","name":"A","nick_name":"A","class_id":"13","group_id":"4","teacher_id":"6","id":"4","group_name":"Science"}]
[{"section_id":"13","name":"A","nick_name":"A","class_id":"13","group_id":"4","teacher_id":"6","id":"4","group_name":"Science"},
{"section_id":"22","name":"B","nick_name":"b","class_id":"13","group_id":"4","teacher_id":"0","id":"4","group_name":"Science"}]
```

If i write `alert(obj.section_id);` it gives me

> error:"undefined".

How can i get a specific value from this json?

Here is my backend function:

```
function get_class_group($class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select('section.*, class_group.*');
        $this->db->from('section');
        $this->db->join('class_group', 'section.group_id = class_group.id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('section.class_id', $class_id);
        $groups = $this->db->get()->result_array();

        foreach ($groups as $row) {
            $value[] = $row;
            echo json_encode($value);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Parse the response to JSON manually using `JSON.parse(str)`. OR use `dataType: 'json'` in `ajax` options.

Comment: obj[0].section_id

Comment: Your response is an array. You have to select the index you need or iterate each element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a each loop, your response is a array of objects,use stringify to turn the string in a object

```
$.ajax({
   url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/get_class_group/' + class_id ,
   success: function(response) {
     response = JSON.stringify(response);
     $.each(response,function(i,v){
       console.log(v.section_id);
     });
   }
});
```

place the echo outside the foreach function

```
foreach ($groups as $row) {
            $value[] = $row;

        }
header('Content-Type: application/json');//add the json header if you want to remove the js stringify function 
echo json_encode($value);
```

Comment: No success. Gives:
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '128' in [{"section_id":"12","name":"A","nick_name":"A","class_id":"13","group_id":"5","teacher_id":"6","id":"5","group_name":"Business"}](…)

Comment: after adding 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
its working. Many many thanks for great help.

Comment: @NishanSingha, if the answer solved your problem, please accept it to allow future visitors to instantly know the solution for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

As such in response you are getting multiple items in the json object you have to use `$.each` to get value for each item.

```
//each loop
$.each(obj,function(key,item){
    alert(item.section_id);
});
```

Please check working snippet below :

```js
var obj =[{
 "section_id": "13",
 "name": "A",
 "nick_name": "A",
 "class_id": "13",
 "group_id": "4",
 "teacher_id": "6",
 "id": "4",
 "group_name": "Science"
}, {
 "section_id": "22",
 "name": "B",
 "nick_name": "b",
 "class_id": "13",
 "group_id": "4",
 "teacher_id": "0",
 "id": "4",
 "group_name": "Science"
}];

$.each(obj,function(i,v){
    console.log(v.section_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gives me error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '128' in [{"section_id":"12","name":"A","nick_name":"A","class_id":"13","group_id":"5","teacher_id":"6","id":"5","group_name":"Business"}](…)

Comment: @NishanSingha see my answer

Comment: @RahulPatel this will not work because he hasn't got an array of object but a string build from multiple echoed object, my answer is the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your response is pure string.

Ensure that backend is adding `Content-Type: application/json` header in the response.

OR:

Try `var res = JSON.parse(response)` so that string is converted to an object.

Answer (score 0):

obj is an array ,so you are getting alert(obj.section_id) as undefined.

use below code to get value

```
alert(obj[0].section_id); // you will get output as 13
alert(obj[1].section_id); // you will get output as 22
```

Answer (score 0):

The output/response seems in json array format. And  to access any particular element from json array, you will need to specify the index position in array.

Please try below to check any particular element data:

alert(obj[0].section_id)

This should alert the 'section_id' of index 0 (i.e, very first element in array)

You can always change index to get data of specific index.